# Meteor Subscriptions ready not working

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've searched and tried for hours but I couldn't come up with any solution for this.

I am writing a Music applications that plays songs from YouTube on a server. I am downloading the Thumbnail and storing it in a [cfs:collection](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) (because I need a gaussian blur version of it later).

My publish method looks like the following:

```
Meteor.publish('currentSong', function() {
    return [Playlist.find({'position': 0}), Thumbnails.find()];
});
```

I had a version which published only the Thumbnail of the current song, but that caused even more problems.

In my Templates onCreated method I subscribe to that (among various other things). I've tried both within a `this.autorun()` method and outside of one.

```
Template.controlpanel.onCreated(function() {
    // subscribe to the publications
    Meteor.subscribe('currentSong');
    Meteor.subscribe('status');
});
```

And then I have a Template helper retrieving the URL of the Thumbnail to actually display it within a `<img src="<url>" />` context:

```
getThumbnail: function() {
    if(Template.instance().subscriptionsReady()){
        var thumbnail = this.thumbnail.getFileRecord();
        if(!$.isEmptyObject(thumbnail)){
            return thumbnail.url({'store': 'Thumbnail'});
        }
    }
}
```

Since I was asked for some more Code, here is a snippet from the actual Template

```
{{#with currentSong}}
<div id="ThumbnailDisplay">     
    <img src="{{getThumbnail}}" alt="{{title}} Thumbnail" id="thumbnail">
</div>
{{/with}}
```

Where currentSong only returns one database entry, listening to the following schema:

```
PlaylistSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
       type: String,
       label: "titlename"
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        label: "titleurl"
    },
    duration: {
        type: Number,
        label: "duration"
    },
    file: {
        type: String,
        label: "filepath",
        optional: true
    },
    position: {
        type: Number,
        label: "postion"
    },
    // id to the Thumbnail CFS Collection object
    thumbnail: {
        // type: String,
        type: FS.File,
        label: "thumbnail"
    }
});
```

Here you can see, that `this.thumbnail` in the context of `{{#with currentSong}}` refers to a FS.File object storing both the Thumbnail and its gaussian blur version.

The Problem is, that when the Template is already loaded and it is switching from one song to another, it works without any Problem. But when there is no song in my playlist, the display part is invisible (The Template is technically rendered, but all the information is inside a `{{#with currentSong}}` Block). And when I insert a song, the display "pops up" and everything is displayed (song title, duration slider and so on) except for the Thumbnail. Once I reload the page, it is there.

I am subscribing to the collection. I check weather the subscriptions are ready or and still it is not working.

I have some other parts in my application where I subscribe in an onCreated context, and still have to use setTimeout `(function(), 100)`, because otherwise the data is not available yet.

I am pretty sure that the Problem lies in front of the screen, that I am missing something or don't fully understand Meteor's subscriptions and which part is reactive or not. But I just don't get it. You help would be much appreciated.

One thing to note is, that I am aware of [iron-router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router) and its capabilities. I have used it in another project of mine. But this app is a sole one page applications having no need for routes at all. So I'd like to restrain from using it.

Comment: You probably need to show a bit more code for us to find the issue. Specifically how you get from the (rather odd...) publication of two different cursors in an array to this.thumbnail

Comment: I have edited the question to give you some more code. I hope this helps. What part of the publication do you find odd? And what would be a proper way to do it?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Sometimes in these cases I find that the client has stopped processing due to errors because a variable is undefined - e.g. this.thumbnail might be undefined at the point that getFileRecord() is called

Comment: I just checked again, no I don't see any error messages. But I tried putting a `console.log(thumbnail.url({'store': 'Thumbnail'}))` in the helper and when I enter the first song (which causes the Template to "appear"), the first message gives me the correct URL, but then I get to consecutive messages stating `null` arising from the same helper. That seems weird.

Comment: So I actually found a hacky solution I don't like at all. With some `console.log()` statements I found out, that at some point the helper actually finds the Thumbnail, but the `thumbnail.url()`return nulls non the less. However if I put this `return thumbnail.url()` in a `setTimeout(function(){...}, 100)` block it works. So my question is, why is there something like `subscriptionsReady()`, when in the end, the subscriptions are not ready. This function even returns true in cases, where the data is not even found. This'd  be the 3rd time in this project I'd have to use  the `setTimeout`  hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after playing around a little more the problem basically is, that the subscriptions are ready, but the CollectionFS files are not.

My solution was now, that I have my helper, reactively setting the correct URL, which always works except when the Template is first rendered.

To tackle that Problem I have an autorun function which changes the image whenever the song changes.

```
this.autorun(function() {
    if(this.subscriptionsReady()){
        var currentSong = Playlist.findOne({'position': 0});
        if(currentSong ){
            var thumbnail = currentSong.thumbnail.getFileRecord();
            $('#thumbnail').attr('src', thumbnail.url());
        }
    }
}.bind(this));
```

It probably is not the ideal solution but it works. For some reason subscriptionReady and CollectionFS do not seem to work together very well.